# Android get first Installation Time returns error

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Hi I am getting this strange error in my app when asking for first installation time using packageinfo!
but only for some devices the error is rare and not often.  why is it happening and is there a workaround?

```
        PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
        info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
        vPname = info.packageName;
        vName = info.versionName;
        vVers = info.versionCode;
        installDate = info.firstInstallTime;
```

gives

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.content.pm.PackageInfo.firstInstallTime
```

minSdkVersion="7"

a list of some devices which returns error:

- Optimus One (thunderg)
- LG-P920 (p920)
- Defy (umts_jordan)
- Infuse (SGH-I997)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because "firstInstallTime" was introduced on API 9 (gingerbread) and above:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime

in order to avoid such errors, it is advised to run a LINT check (using the "V" button near the run button, for example). LINT has plenty of errors and warnings that could help you get a better code. you can even make it check for problems on each save operation.

Of course, it has bugs and missing checks too, even for this matter.

Comment: @user1616685 it's also advised to always update the ADT&SDK to the latest version and use the most recent targetSdk API number in the manifest, in order to avoid such problems. however, it's still the best to just run the app from time to time on old android versions.

Comment: But how could such an error appear at runtime, if you have already compiled apk?

Comment: @mdavid The class in the framework didn't have this field on API 8 and below . the compiled code of the app is ok, but it assumes the existence of this field. This is also why you can try to use the action bar, even if you use API 10 and below. It will warn you about it, but you still can do it. In order to avoid crashes, you can perform checks on the version number.